# Are there any Ubuntu Tablets for sale in the U.S.?

Tags: tablet, ubuntu-touch

Are there any tablets preinstalled with Ubuntu for sale in the United States? If so, who makes them and where can they be purchased?

Comment: Afaik, there are no tablet PCs with Ubuntu preinstalled.

Comment: omgubuntu.co.uk shared a story about some ubuntu tablets but i don't have a link right now and i don't remember if the us were mentioned at all. you can check it , though - the message is rather new and will be on one of the first pages

Comment: I believe you won't have any fun using Ubuntu on a purely touch based tablet PC. It just was not made for such things.

Comment: @dAnjou, oh.. Unity was BORN for tablets and so was Gnome Shell

Answer (score 3):

These are the tablets mentioned in OMGUBUNTU
[image: ekoore]

[image]
[image]

[here's the link](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/tag/tablet/)

Comment: I think they are only sold in Europe, i kinda asked them but they didn't mentioned the U.S. or the rest of America for that matter.